# can not load javascript drow2d canvas with manuall extends cods

Tags: javascript, json, draw2d

I have added some functionality to my objects in draw2d canvas. such as :

```
    var MyConnection= draw2d.Connection.extend({
    init:function(attr){
        this._super(attr);
        this.setRouter(new draw2d.layout.connection.VertexRouter());
        this.setOutlineStroke(1);
        this.setOutlineColor("#000000");
        this.setStroke(3);
        this.setColor('#ffffff');
        this.setRadius(150);
        this.conectionResult={"src":{"nms":true,"trg":true},"trg":{"nms":true,"src":"true"}};
    },


    onContextMenu:function(x,y){
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: 'body',
            events:{
                hide:function(){ $.contextMenu( 'destroy' ); }
            },
            callback: $.proxy(function(key, options){
                switch(key){
                    case "check":
                        result = this.checkConection();
                        this.conectionResult=result;
                        console.log(result);
                        if(result.src.trg && result.trg.src){
                            this.setColor("#FFFFFF");
                        }else{
                            this.setColor("#FF4422");
                        }
                    break;
                    case "report":
                        message=[];
                        result=this.conectionResult;
                        if(result.src.trg && result.trg.src){
                            alert("OK");
                        }else{
                            src=this.getSource();
                            trg=this.getTarget();
                            if(result.src.nms){
                                message.push("NMS Can See "+src.userData.dev_name);
                                if(result.src.trg){
                                    message.push(src.userData.dev_name +" Can See "+trg.userData.dev_name);
                                }else{
                                    message.push(src.userData.dev_name +" CAN NOT See "+trg.userData.dev_name);
                                }
                            }else{
                               message.push("NMS CAN NOT See "+trg.userData.dev_name);
                               if(result.src.trg){
                                   message.push(src.userData.dev_name +"Can See "+trg.userData.dev_name);
                               }else{
                                   message.push(src.userData.dev_name +"CAN NOT See "+trg.userData.dev_name+" Or NMS Can not confirm it");
                               }
                            }

                            if(result.trg.nms){
                                message.push("NMS Can See "+trg.userData.dev_name);
                                if(result.trg.src){
                                    message.push(trg.userData.dev_name +" Can See "+src.usedData.dev_name);
                                }else{
                                    message.push(trg.userData.dev_name +" CAN NOT See "+src.userData.dev_name);
                                }
                            }else{
                                message.push("NMS CAN NOT See "+trg.dev_name);
                                if(result.src.trg){
                                    message.push(src.userData.dev_name +" Can See "+trg.userData.dev_name);
                                }else{
                                    message.push(src.userData.dev_name +" CAN NOT See "+trg.userData.dev_name+" Or NMS Can not confirm it.");
                                }
                            }
                            alert(message.join("\n"));
                        }
                    break;
                    case "delete":

                        var cmd = new draw2d.command.CommandDelete(this);
                        this.getCanvas().getCommandStack().execute(cmd);
                    default:
                    break;
                }

            },this),
            x:x,
            y:y,
            items:
            {
                "check":{name:"Check", icon:"edit"},
                "report":{name:"Report",icon:"edit"},
                "sep1":   "---------"
               ,"delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"}
            }
        });
    },
    checkConection:function(){
        src=this.getSource();
        trg=this.getTarget();
        console.log("Source IP:"+src.userData.ip+", Target Ip:"+trg.userData.ip);
        results={"src":{"nms":false,"trg":false},"trg":{"nms":false,"src":false}};
        $.ajax({
            url:"***/index.php?r=/******/check-conection&src="+src.userData.ip+"&trg="+trg.userData.ip,
            async:false,
            success: function(result){
                results=result;
            }
        });
        console.log(results);
        this.conectionResult=results;
        this.setConectionColor();
        return results;
    },
    setConectionColor:function(){
        result=this.conectionResult;
        console.log(result);
        if(result.src.trg && result.trg.src){
            this.setColor("#FFFFFF");
        }else{
            this.setColor("#FF4422");
        }
    }
});
```

~
i used below method to save them via AJAX request in server.

```
    function saveTopology(){
    var writer = new draw2d.io.json.Writer();
    writer.marshal(canvas, function(json){
        var jsonTxt = JSON.stringify(json,null,2);                        .
        $("pre").text(jsonTxt);
     });
    alert($("pre").text());
    draw2d=JSON.stringify(JSON.parse($("pre").html()));
    var data={
        id      :1,
        draw2d : draw2d,
        map_id : 1
    };
    var url = "topology/save";
    result = AjaxResponce(url,data,"POST");
    $("pre").html(result);
    displayJSON(canvas);

}
```

and used below to reload it for  next times.

```
    function setTopology(){
    write2status("Requesting Topology of map_id 1 ...");
    draw2d.Configuration.factory.createConnection = function (sourcePort, targetPort) {
        var conn = new MyConnection({});
        return conn;
    };
    var topology = AjaxResponce("topology/get-topology",{tplg_id:tplg_id});
    console.log(topology);
    data = topology;
    var bg_map = "url('"+data.bg_map+"')";
    var width = data.width;
    var height = data.height;
    var background_size = height+"px "+width+"px ";
    if(typeof(data.draw2d)==="Array"){
        $.each(data.draw2d,function(index,item){
            if(typeof(item.userData) != "undefined" &&Object.keys(item.userData).length >0){
                if(typeof(item.userData.dev_id) !== "undefined")
                    usedDevices.push(item.userData.dev_id);
            }
        });
    }
    topology=JSON.stringify(data.draw2d);
    $(".ui-droppable").css({"background-image":bg_map});
    $(".ui-droppable").css({"height":parseInt(height)*1.1});
    $(".ui-droppable").css({"width":parseInt(width)*1.1});
    write2status("Adding map to page...");
    $("pre#json").html(topology);
    write2status("Map added...");
}
```

I set

```
draw2d.Configuration.factory.createConnection = function (sourcePort, targetPort) {
    var conn = new MyConnection({});
    return conn;
};`
```

The functionalities works when i open a new form but nor added functionalities loads after reloading the page while they are asigned to any new objects that add to page after reload.
Can any one help me to solve this problem?

Comment: is it possible to re-generate all items one by one using saved json or draw2d methods, after loading?

In this case ever things will work properly

Comment: I know that the problem is my extend class <first block of this question codes> not assign to saved items. So i need to assign if for loaded diagram before or after loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve the problem but not sure is a correct way.
I just changed

```
 var MyConnection= draw2d.Connection.extend({
```

in first code to

```
 draw2d.Connection = draw2d.Connection.extend({
```

then removed related codes of 3th file. in this case Draw2d loads My connection instead of default function.